# How to plot a periodic multipart function with constant sections in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to plot a periodic function with two different parts. The first part is the actual function und the second part is a flat line at the last value. While trying to implement this with pgfplots I've seen a strange behavior: If I define the function in the flat line section with function(CONST) the result isn't a constant. I think pgfplots is replacing the CONST with an x and just plots the normal function.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{trig format plots=rad, compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    declare function={%
        funco(\x)= (x+sin(x));
        output(\x)= %
            and(\x >= 0*pi, \x < 1*pi) * (funco(x)) +
            and(\x >= 1*pi, \x < 2*pi) * (funco(1*pi)) +
            and(\x >= 2*pi, \x < 3*pi) * (funco(x)) +
            and(\x >= 3*pi, \x < 4*pi) * (funco(3*pi)) +
            and(\x >= 4*pi, \x < 5*pi) * (funco(x))
            ;
    }
]
\begin{axis}[]
    \addplot[domain=0:5*pi, samples=260]{output(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result:
[image]

This is the result I would expect:
[image]

So my questions are:

- Why is the result not as expected?
- What do I need to change to get the expected result?
- Is there a more simple way to declare functions like that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You simply forgot to put backslashes in front of the `x`es when defining the function in Ti*k*Z (!).

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{trig format plots=rad, compat=1.14}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    declare function={%
        funco(\x)= (\x+sin(\x));
        output(\x)= %
            and(\x >= 0*pi, \x < 1*pi)* (funco(\x))) +
            and(\x >= 1*pi, \x < 2*pi) * (funco(1*pi)) +
            and(\x >= 2*pi, \x < 3*pi) * (funco(\x)) +
            and(\x >= 3*pi, \x < 4*pi) * (funco(3*pi)) +
            and(\x >= 4*pi, \x < 5*pi) * (funco(\x))
            ;
    }
]
\begin{axis}[]
    \addplot[domain=0:5*pi, samples=260]{output(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the question of whether or not there is a more elegant way of defining such functions. The answer is yes, there is, but the bad news is that, as of now, functions like `iseven` do not yet cooperate with `fpu`, and can thus not be used in `pgfplots`. The good news is that it is easy to add this function.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{trig format plots=rad, compat=1.14}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{isevenFPU}{1}{%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathsetcount\c@pgfmath@counta{abs(int(#1))}%
    \ifodd\c@pgfmath@counta
      \def\pgfmathresult{0}%
    \else
      \def\pgfmathresult{1}%
    \fi
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    declare function={%
        funco(\x)= (\x+sin(\x));
        soutput(\x)= %
            ifthenelse(isevenFPU(int(\x/pi)),funco(\x),funco(int(\x/pi)*pi));
    }
]
\begin{axis}[]
    \addplot[domain=0:5*pi, samples=260]{soutput(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for additional request number 1:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{trig format plots=rad, compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    declare function={%
        funco(\x)= (\x+sin(\x));
        soutput(\x)= %
            ifthenelse(\x-4*int(\x/4)<=2.5,funco(\x),funco(4*int(\x/4)+2.5));
    }
]
\begin{axis}[]
    \addplot[domain=0:24, samples=260]{soutput(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the easy solution and shame on me for not seeing this. I have two additional questions regarding your elegant way of defining the functions. `iseven` only works if I divide the function in multiples of pi. Is there a possibility to devide the function for example at 1/2.5/4/5.5 and so on? Second thing is I would like to substract the value from the last flat line from the next part of the function to get the plot in red: [link](https://i.imgur.com/zwgGKEM.png)

Comment: @switches The first additional request can be implemented rather easily, I believe, but not the second one since this requires some sort of a loop. I am not saying that the second request is impossible, but I do not see a very short solution. I added the first one to the answer and would kindly ask you to ask a separate question (which is free of charge).